# Finding a basis for $V, W, V+W$ and $V \cap W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

**Problem:** Let \begin{align*} V = \left\{(x,y,z,u) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid y+z+u = 0 \right\} \end{align*} and \begin{align*} W = \left\{(x,y,z,u) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x+y = 0, z = 2u \right\} \end{align*} be two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Find a basis for $V, W, V+W$ and $V \cap W$.

**Attempt at solution:** To find a basis for $V$ I did the following. Since it says $y+z+u = 0$, we have that $u = -y-z$. Hence a general representation of a vector in $V$ is $(x,y,z,-y-z)$. Then a basis can be found by considering \begin{align*} (x,y,z,-y-z) = x(1,0,0,0) + y(0,1,0,-1) + z (0,0,1,-1). \end{align*} Hence \begin{align*} \left\{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,-1), (0,0,1,-1)\right\} \end{align*} forms a basis for $V$.

Then for $W$ we have $y=-x$. Hence a general representation is $(x,-x, 2u, u)$, and so \begin{align*} (x,-x, 2u, u) = x(1,-1,0,0) + u(0,0,2,1), \end{align*} so that $\left\{(1,-1,0,0),(0,0,2,1)\right\}$ is a basis for $W$.

For $V+W$ I just added the general representations: $(x,y,z,-y-z) + (x,-x,2u,u) = (2x,y-x,z+2u,-y-z+u)$.  Hence \begin{align*} (2x,y-x,z+2u,-y-z+u) = x(2,-1,0,0) + y(0,1,0,-1) + z (0,0,1,-1) + u(0,0,2,1) \end{align*} so that it also forms a basis.

Can someone tell me if my reasoning is correct? Also, for $V \cap W$ I have no idea what to do, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: For your attempt at $V + W$, note that in $(x, y, z, -y - z)$ and in $(x, -x, 2u, u)$, the two $x$s need not be the same. it might be clearer to work with $(x_1, y, z, -y-z)$ and $(x_2, -x_2, 2u, u)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasonings for calculating the basis for $V$ and $W$ are correct. For $V+W$, as qaphla pointed out in the comment, the two $x$'s need not be the same. You can calculate the basis for $V+W$ in the following manner. Let $\mathcal{B}_1=\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,-1),(0,0,1,-1)\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_2=\{(1,-1,0,0),(0,0,2,1)\}$ be basis for $V$ and $W$, respectively. Then the space spanned by $\mathcal{B}_1\cup\mathcal{B}_2$ is contained in $V+W$. It is easy to verify that the subspace spanned by $\mathcal{B}_1\cup\mathcal{B}_2$ is $\mathbb{R}^4$. Hence $V+W=\mathbb{R}^4$.

For $V\cap W$, remember what does the $\cap$ symbol mean: the vectors in $V\cap W$ satify the properties of both $V$ **and** $W$. So,

$$V\cap W=\{(x,y,z,u)\in\mathbb{R}^4\;|\;y+z+u=0,\;x+y=0\;\text{and}\;z=2u\}$$

Can you see that a basis for this space is $\mathcal{B}_{V\cap W}=\{(3,-3,2,1)\}$?

Now compare this results with the equation: $$\text{dim}(V+W)=\text{dim}(V)+\text{dim}(W)-\text{dim}(V\cap W)$$

Comment: If we do $B_1 \cup B_2$, then we have $5$ vectors? Then this set must be linearly dependent and thus cannot be a basis for $V+W$?

Comment: But I see that $\left\{(3,-3,2,1)\right\}$ is a basis for $V \cap W$. On the basis of last equation, we have $\dim(V + W) = 4$. So we must have $4$ vectors?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted you to see! One of those 5 vector of $\mathcal{B}_1\cup\mathcal{B}_2$ can be written as a linear combination of the others, and these others are linearly independent. You could also conclude that $V+W=\mathbb{R}^4$ by the last equation and without having to calculate explicitly a basis for $V+W$: any basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ will work.

Comment: How do I find which one is a linear combination of the others? The basisvectors I mean.